# Troubleshooting intermittent RDP disconnections

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

I use RDP to connect back to my home systems for various reasons from somewhere else. The host runs the current windows 11 insider (currently Version 22H2/Build 25169.1000).The client's on windows 10, using the default/MS RDP client.  I have intermittent disconnects 'early' on when I connect, either entirely, or more rarely with the following error - so often maybe 5-6 disconnects over 20-30 minutes, then a rock solid connection over the rest of the day.

[image]

When I have more regular disconnections with no error messages - I experimented by running ping -t on the client to the host - seems I occasionally have ping spikes of about 50ms up to 200ms, which result in the disconnections. The average is 30ms, which is still usable. I need to think of a good way to figure out if this time of day related or something else.

While I'm over a tethered/mobile connection, its generally stable when it works. Its responsive, I'm usually on a good connection over UDP. I'm looking more for "where do I look to see what actually happened" over resolving this. Where should I look or error logging and such for RDP?

Comment: Best bet here is to run network trace to ETL files using netsh commands on both client and server sides I think. Then with Microsoft Message Analyzer to export those to CAP or PCAP and then inspeact the traffic in the captured traces. That usually helps me see what's going on with nigh network latency issues with higher than usual ping times. I assume you connect VPN then to the RDP, but if RDP is wide open, others could be trying brute force connections of DOS across the Internet to the RDP connection you need to access. Quick thoughts!

Comment: Ah, so... I ended up quitting that job so... I don't really have access to the client machine. I didn't have control of the RDP client machine (which was why I was using the RDP connection for stuff that was "personal") so a VPN wasn't an option

Comment: Just quit that job, nice!! Wireshark and those NETSH commands and transforms have always been my friend troublshooting Windows network issues, so just FYI there at a minimum I support. Keep chugging along sir, choo choo on the IT train, live, breath and eat IT!! Roof...